# Why does destructor run into unallocated memory?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a singly-linked, circular linked list and am writing a destructor to delete all the nodes. The destructor first severs the head from the rest of the lest to prevent infinite circulation and then I loop through the list and delete all the nodes, eventually, the loop comes back to the head and deletes it as well. In the program I check to make sure that the pointer to the nodes is not NULL and I ran the debugger and it shows that it is NULL at a point which should end the loop, but instead the loop continues and runs into un-allocated memory. Here is my code:

```
    node<T> *cur = head;
    node<T> *nxt = head->next;
    if (nxt) cur->next = nullptr;
    cur = nxt;

    // walk through the list and delete nodes
    while (cur) {
        cur = cur->next;
        delete cur;
    }
```

**EDIT:** Changed code to

```
  node<T> *cur = head;
    node<T> *nxt = head->next;
    if (nxt) cur->next = nullptr;
    cur = nxt;

    // walk through the list and delete nodes
    while (cur) {
        nxt = cur->next;
        delete cur;
        cur = nxt;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** Changed code once more to handle edge cases, same problem still occurs.

```
if (head ==  NULL) return;
    else if (head->next == head) delete head;
    else {
        node<T> *cur = head;
        node<T> *nxt = head->next;
        cur->next = nullptr;
        cur = nxt;
        while(cur) {
            nxt = cur -> next;
            delete cur;
            cur = nxt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Follow your loop logic more carefully.  `delete cur;` -- so what happens to `cur` after that line?  You've destroyed it.  So what happens on `while(cur)`?

Comment: Ah, probably need a temp pointer

Comment: Problem had to do with my remove function, the function was deleting the head of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the severing, your code to walk the list while deleting elements would be just as faulty in a non-circular list. You advance the pointer *then* delete what it points to (the next item).

You need to delete the *current* item  (but, of course, you also need to have extracted its `next` field before that point because, once deleted, all content becomes undefined), something like:

```
while (cur != nullptr) {
    node<T> *toDelete = cur;
    cur = cur->next;
    delete toDelete;
}
```

---

In terms of a full solution to what you need, the *algorithm* should be:

```
def delCircList(head):
    # Ignore empty list.

    if head == null:
        return

    # Special for one-element list.

    if head.next == head:
        free head
        return

    # Sever link and set start point.

    curr = head.next
    head.next = null

    # Use normal deletion algorithm.

    while curr != null:
        toDelete = curr
        curr = curr.next
        free toDelete
```

Comment: Yup, changed it and still does not exit loop

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide: you should be aware that, prior to severing, `if (nxt)` will *never* be false (because it's a circular list). Suggest you look at my added pseudo-code as a useful baseline.

Comment: This is similar to my implementation, what is failing is the loop check, as I said I ran debugger and the value of cur is null when the check occurs but does not exit loop

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide: see my first comment above. Because `nxt` will never be null in a circular (non-severed) list, you can't use that to sever the list. You therefore have an infinite loop becaue it's still circular. You're better off using my posted pseudocode to handle empty (head == null) and one-element (`head.next == head`) lists as special cases, then do the iteration work iff those cases aren't true.

Comment: If it's never false the list should always be severed? Not the other way round.

Comment: The boolean value of a pointer is true when `ptr != NULL`, so by your reasoning the severing should always occur.

Comment: Oh yeah, good point. Still, I'd suggest starting with the pseudo-code I provided - I've tested that to work in Python.

Comment: Ok, I will, however I still don't understand why what I am doing is not working

Comment: Well, `free head` isn't really valid Python but you're right - I consider Python (sans complex stuff like list comprehensions) the ideal pseudo-code language. To be honest, I can't see why your updated code wouldn't work either (other than if `head == nullptr`), I've checked it by hand with size 1, 2 and 3. But you would have to absolutely certain the circular list is correct beforehand.

Comment: Hm, it seems that in main, when the destructor should be called, the list is not malformed, but when destructor is actually called the list seems to be unallocated

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide, that sounds like the problem lies outside the destructor call, perhaps the list has been modified by something else.